# Multiple filters in ng-repeat where one requires exact matching

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have written this filters in `ng-repeat` and this works correctly.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{ Name:search, Country:country, MembershipType:membership} | filter: {Gender: gender}: true>
```

Now I need a function that filters with same criterion. I have written this

```
$scope.getData = function () {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.data, { Name: $scope.search, Country: $scope.country, MembershipType: $scope.membership, Gender: $scope.gender })
}
```

Others works fine, but this function does not return the exact match of the gender.

What should I do in the function?

Comment: Try this `return $filter('filter')($scope.data, { Name: $scope.search, Country: $scope.country, MembershipType: $scope.membership, Gender: $scope.gender},true )`

Comment: hadijz, is this return the only exact match of gender?

Comment: doesnot work this time too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a second parameter for using exact match. Just as in your html you can use the filter twice:

```
$scope.getData = function () {

    var filter = $filter('filter');

    // First filter the non-exact
    var filtered = filter($scope.data, { 
        Name: $scope.search, 
        Country: $scope.country, 
        MembershipType: $scope.membership 
    });

    // then the exact filters
    var genderFiltered = filter(filtered, { 
        Gender: $scope.gender 
    }, true);

    return genderFiltered;
}
```

Comment: OMG. Me also trying to post this same here :( . +1

Answer (score 0):

Am also tried the same as @devqon answer. but can't post here for the duplicate answer, So I just changing my code like below .

> Your ng-rpeate having two filters to two time filter the data. So, you should write your code like filter of filter way.

```
$scope.getData = function () {
        return $filter('filter')(($filter('filter')($scope.data, { Name: $scope.search, 
            Country: $scope.country, MembershipType: $scope.membership }), { 
            Gender: $scope.gender 
            }, true);
}
```